# How to echo out the values of this array?

Tags: php, arrays, key

How to echo out the values individually of this array?

```
Array ( [0] => 20120514 [1] => My Event 3 )
```

so

```
 echo $value[0]; etc
```

I have this so far:

```
foreach (json_decode($json_data_string, true) as $item) {

$eventDate = trim($item['date']);

    // positive limit
    
   $myarray = (explode(',', $eventDate, 2));

foreach ($myarray as $value) {
   echo $value;
}
```

This echo's out the whole string no as an array. and if i do this?

```
  echo $value[0};
```

Then I only get 2 characters of it??

The print_r :

```
Array ( [0] => 20120430 [1] => My Event 1 )
```

Comment: Don't know much PHP but is this really correct syntax: `echo $value[0};` or do you mean `echo $value[0];`

Comment: can you show us the `print_r($myarray);` ?

Comment: added to question. yep that is a mistake should be [0] but they just echos 2M for some reason?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
   echo $val;
}
```

Comment: That just echos this 20120430My Event 1. How do i select just My Event 1. ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple routine for an array of primitive elements:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($mySimpleArray); $i++)
{
   echo $mySimpleArray[$i] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need the set key and value in foreach loop for that:

```
foreach($item AS $key -> $value) {
echo $value;
}
```

this should do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is in your explode statement

```
//$item['date'] presumably = 20120514.  Do a print of this
$eventDate = trim($item['date']);

//This explodes on , but there is no , in $eventDate
//You also have a limit of 2 set in the below explode statement
$myarray = (explode(',', $eventDate, 2));

 //$myarray is currently = to '20'

 foreach ($myarray as $value) {
    //Now you are iterating through a string
    echo $value;
 }
```

Try changing your initial $item['date'] to be 2012,04,30 if that's what you're trying to do.  Otherwise I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to print.

Answer (score 1):

```
var_dump($value)
```

it solved my problem, hope yours too.