# php fgets explode shows "Array." instead of $array

Tags: php, arrays, fopen, explode

I am trying to convert a plain text logfile (no wordwrap) into something more readable.
php-file

```
<?php
    $log = fopen("/home/raspi/scripts/logs/test.log", "r");

    while (!feof($log)){

    $arrM = explode("|",fgets($log));

    echo "$arrM . <br>";
        }
    fclose($log)
?>
```

Whenever there is a `|` in the logfile the php script should change it to `<br>` in the output.
However, when opening the php file, all I get is 
`Array .
Array .`

Content of the logfile 
`Sachen|Enter|nochmal Enter|Und schon wieder Enter`. I am a beginner and started reading about fopen and explode. Thought this would be just what I needed but something is wrong...? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Because when you explode you are creating an array. You have to loop through them. Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584784/how-to-echo-out-the-values-of-this-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) for print array (developer-output)

```
<?php
$log = fopen("/home/raspi/scripts/logs/test.log", "r");

while (!feof($log)){

    $arrM = explode("|",fgets($log));

    //echo "$arrM . <br>";
    print_r($arrM);
}
fclose($log)
?>
```

[echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) print one or more strings

```
<?php
$log = fopen("/home/raspi/scripts/logs/test.log", "r");

while (!feof($log)){

   $arrM = explode("|",fgets($log));

   //echo "$arrM . <br>";
   foreach($arrM as $string){
       echo $string . '<br>';
   }
}
fclose($log)
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you can't output an array with `echo`, you'd need to loop like
`foreach ($arrM as $row) echo $row;` or use `var_dump($arrM)` for 'developer-output' or `print_r($arrM)` alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

use `echo "<pre>";print_r($arrM);`

Reason , if an array is printed in echo , PHP will show you Array, so you better have a look whats coming thru print_r and accordingly you can access variable ,or put it in loop.

Comment: Why downvotes ?I gave proper explanation with answer.